# Выбрать значение переменной из адресной строки

Tags: php

Всем привет.
Подскажите,как выдернуть один параметр из строки,и вывести его через echo?
Идёт GET запрос вида mysite.ru/start?id=xxxxx&city=xxx

Необходимо выдернуть id и просто вывести,как текст через echo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого можно обратиться к массиву `$_GET`, куда помещаются все GET-параметры

```
<?php
echo $_GET['id'];
```

См. в документации: [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php)